# Is there a way of obtaining the user ID of the profile being edited in wp-admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way of obtaining the user ID of the profile being edited in wp-admin?

I know it's in the URL if you are editing a user, EX: ./wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=427. Could always $_GET['user_id'] to retrieve the user's ID.

Is there an easy or broad way of retrieving the user ID of the current user profile being edited in wp-admin?

Comment: You have already answered your own question...?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69461/how-to-obtain-the-user-id-of-the-current-profile-being-edited-in-wp-admin

Answer (score 1):

You have already stated you are able to get the `ID` via `$_GET`...

Another way is via `get_current_user_id()` - this assumes you are the user being edited. (@cabrerahector)

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

Another way is to hook onto `edit_user_profile_update` action hook, which will pass the currently edited user into your call back function. It is possible that this will only work when editing a profile other than your own.

```
do_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', my_user_function() )
function my_user_function(int $user_id){
  // $user_id is currently edited user
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile_update/

Comment: Except that `get_current_user_id()` returns "_(int) The current user's ID, or 0 if no user is logged in_" which doesn't seem to be what the OP is looking for. Apparently (s)he wants to get the ID of the user that's currently being edited.